# AppEngine task to create many entities

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, mapreduce

I'm building an application for people attending events. I need to create a Ticket entity for a subset of Person entities, for a specific Event. The amount of people may exceed 50,000 entities.

Obviously I can't just do a for-loop where I iterate over a Person query and generate these Tickets.

How do I structure this on App Engine, is there a way to take advantage of MapReduce?

Comment: By MapReduce, I mean perhaps mapping every Person entity and checking if they're attending the Event, then creating the Ticket for them. Isn't this hugely inefficient though, if the people attending the event is < 1% of the whole Person set?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the [Deferred library](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html). You can spool up a bunch of task queues in parrallel to do the work that you want. You may want to look at the [Mapper example class](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html) in the google docs which may help push you in the right direction.

Comment: I've considered using something like the Mapper class. My only concern is that the processing happens in serial - what if I have 1 million Person entities to run through, the job would run forever.

Comment: It'd certainly run for a long time but the deferred task gets an exception when its timeslot is running out allowing it to requeue the next item. Also, you could kick off many deferred tasks working against your dataset, pass in segregation data as part of the task (i.e. a start point and end point) and have each one only iterate over that chunk. That way you get to slice and dice your workload

Comment: If you have 1 million people attending an event, and that's less than 1% of your database... congratulations?

Comment: @Nick My point was that MapReduce seems appropriate for 1 million, but Mapper may be more appropriate for a smaller set. So is it better to err on the side of parallelism without the same efficiency?

Comment: @Nikolaj For realistic numbers of tickets (50k), serial with deferred shouldn't take too long, though you'd want to benchmark that, to be sure. Or, you could wait for mapreduce to add support for mapping over filtered datasets, or add your own sharding to deferred tasks, as @Wolfwyrd suggests. Some of this depends on how you generate tickets - do you need to assign unique seat numbers, for instance?

Comment: @Nick There isn't any processing of tickets that needs a guarantee of uniqueness or depends on state across the data like that. Does this influence the solution in other ways than the question of parallel vs. serial?

Comment: @Nikolaj Well, it does make me wonder what it is that your ticket generation _does_ do. Can't you just take the 'reservations' and declare them by fiat to be 'tickets'?

Comment: @Nick There are no reservations. There are people and events, with some properties on the Person class that specifies if a ticket should be created for a specific event.

Comment: @NickJohnson let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1462/discussion-between-nikolaj-and-nick-johnson)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate in a single for loop if you the Backend where a request can last for long. But such long running processes are not a good thing in my opinion. I guess proper use of task queues is more than enough.

I read about the Deferred library. Sometimes it behaves strangely and pickling your data can introduce some headaches. I could for the TaskQueue API

Answer (score 0):

I do not suggest [Deferred Library](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html), although it's very easy to write code, the disadvantage is it will pickle your data, put it into one entity, and load and unpickle it later that cost a lot of overhead. Puts 30K entities costs me about **3 CPU Hours**!

The **cheapest** way is just use the [Task Queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) that split the Person and enqueue with keys or other positional information. Insert same 30K entities used less than **1 CPU Hour**.

In your question, fetch 1 million entities and run over is very fast depends on GAE's design, just do it. The slowest part is store the new Ticket entity.

*BTW,
why not just `Person.all().filter("something like attending events")`.*